# How would you call a form where you fill in info about what you worked on?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am missing correct word here... Can someone help?

Imagine that a company works remotely due to Coronavirus. The company uses an internal website where every worker registers the info about the work he has done that day.

So, the worker (let's say Robert) simply fills in a **form** where he writes, for example:

- 9:00-14:15 - work on the design of company's product
- 14:15-15:30 - help out Monica with this and that
- 15:30-17:00 - meeting with client

How would you call the above form that Robert just filled? I am thinking... worksheet. But that does not say much about actual registering the work tasks.

The 'form' is too general. I am looking for something concise that would sum up.

Comment: Wikipedia: - [*a **timesheet** (or **time sheet**) is a method for recording the amount of a worker's time spent on each job.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timesheet)

Comment: In every office where I have worked, it was called a time sheet. *But that does not say much about actual registering the work tasks* – it was never intended to be a substitute for a detailed log of each job. It was for time analysis, and to be used for billing clients.

Comment: i think a report would do if you don't wanna use time sheet.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [**log**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/log):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> 4 : a record of performance, events, or day-to-day activities

In the context of the question, the people are filling out an *activity* ***log***. Or, depending on how it's viewed, *activity-**log** entries* in a [*logbook*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/logbook).

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to do better than this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the term  ***[résumé:](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/it/amp/inglese/resume)***

> A résumé is a short account, either spoken or written, of something that has happened or that someone has said or written.

> - We began each planning meeting with a résumé of how we were doing as a division.

(Collins)